# Google Colab + Google Drive keep renaming and deleting files

Tags: tensorflow, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am training a model on Google Colab and I mounted my Drive, which's also synced to my desktop (Mac). I'm running a script that creates tfrecord files. For some reason, a file saved as `train.record` keeps getting renamed to `train 2.record` as if there is another copy - although there isn't. I tried to delete the file multiple times and even deleted the folder itself. I thought it was a syncing issue, but I checked both the folders on the cloud and on the desktop. I also tried restarting the runtime multiple times.

The following files keep getting automatically trashed by Google Drive. Even when I place them in different folders:

[image]

Is this a syncing cache issue?

Comment: Please check if there are any other files with the same name train.record either in the same directory or in a directory that google drive considers when syncing. Sometimes, drive might rename files automatically to avoid conflicts.